# Не отрисовывается страница в React приложении

Tags: reactjs

Перестала отрисовываться стр после подключения Redux[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Редюсер нужно передать в `createStore`:

```
let store = createStore(reducers);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
мой redux:



import { combineReducers, createStore } from "redux";
import sidebarReducer from "./sidebarReducer";
import profileReducer from "./profileReducer";
import dialogsReducer from "./dialogsReducer";
debugger;
let reducers = combineReducers({
    profilePage: profileReducer,
    dialogsPage: dialogsReducer,
    sidebar: sidebarReducer,
});
let store = createStore();
export default store;
```

Comment: Не пишите дополнения к вопросу в ответе - нажмите ссылку "править" под вопросом и дополните его вашим кодом. Данный ответ следует удалить.